# how to get width/ height of video file using S3FS, FFMPEG in ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, ffmpeg, s3fs

at the moment I succeed to install S3FS & FFMPEG in ec2, but i don't know why I can't get information about height and width of a video file, but another properties such as duration, audio stream, etc are shown,

I already try in local within same a video file, and all properties are shown (within width and height).

does anyone know, what's wrong with this ?

Comment: Are you trying to do this with a video file on s3? Although I think the properties are somewhat dependent on the codec used.

Comment: yes, could you give me more explanation ?

Comment: When you have a normal disk volume, applications can read or write to blocks within a file. The attributes that determine the size are within certain blocks. S3 does not work like a normal disk volume even if s3fs makes it look like one. It treats objects (files) in its entirety. You will probably need to do any processing before you move it to s3 or copy it from s3 to get the data you need.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to recommend to take a look at the new project RioFS (Userspace S3 filesystem): https://github.com/skoobe/riofs.

This project is “s3fs” alternative, the main advantages comparing to “s3fs” are: simplicity, the speed of operations and bugs-free code. Currently [the project](https://github.com/skoobe/riofs) is in the “testing” state, but it's been running on several high-loaded fileservers for quite some time.

We are seeking for more people to join our project and help with the testing. From our side we offer quick bugs fix and will listen to your requests to add new features.

Regarding your issue, RioFS is able to read "requested" blocks of files, for example I tried to get properties of a video file stored on S3:

1. Mounted RioFS:

`./riofs -c ../riofs.conf.xml http://s3.amazonaws.com bucket_name mnt/`

1. Run `ffprobe`:

`ffprobe mnt/big_buck_bunny_480p_surround-fix.avi`

1. Got this result:

`Input #0, avi, from 'mnt/big_buck_bunny_480p_surround-fix.avi':
  Duration: 00:09:56.46, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2957 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (FMP4 / 0x34504D46), yuv420p, 854x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 427:240], 24 tbr, 24 tbn, 24 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: ac3 ([0] [0][0] / 0x2000), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 448 kb/s`

Hope it helps you and we are looking forward to seeing you joined our community !